# How to create a Jetstream Project via Composer in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, web, laravel-jetstream

I just upgraded to laravel 8, and want to use jetstream package but i am having issues installing it. Can someone tell complete procedure of how to install Laravel 8 jetstream project via composer and authentication too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in laravel/installer its easy

```
laravel new project --jet
```

but with composer

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
// then
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
// or
php artisan jetstream:install inertia --teams

npm install && npm run dev
```

and for migrations just run this:

```
php artisan migrate
```

all in jetstream docs this link: https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/installation.html#composer-installation

Answer (score 1):

just adding my few cents to the answer given by @TEFO. If in case you get an error saying

> The "--jet" option does not exist

, then you will have to update your laravel installer by running

> composer global update