# Tailwind not working when applying stylesheet in Layout

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I have a big problem. I tried to use Tailwind in a new Laravel project following exactly all the documentation but as soon as I try to put the `<link>` to the `css/app.css` the HTML just stop working in the browser (localhost).

I tried also starting a new Laravel project with JetStream, but it does the same thing.

I also tried installing an older version of Tailwind but nothing seems to work.
I don't really know what to search for at this point.

Any help?

Comment: I think you need to look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827708/how-to-create-a-jetstream-project-via-composer-in-laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

you can use tailwindCss in laravel with breeze package or Jetstream

**1- with Breeze:**

```
//composer package

composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

then

```
php artisan breeze:install
```

**Or Breeze with Inertia**

```
php artisan breeze:install --inertia
```

**Finalizing The Installation**

```
  npm install
    
    npm run dev
    
    php artisan migrate
```

**2- with Jetstream**

```
//composer package

composer require laravel/jetstream
```

***Install Jetstream With Livewir**e*

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire

php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams
```

***Or, Install Jetstream With Inertia***

```
php artisan jetstream:install inertia

php artisan jetstream:install inertia --teams
```

**Finalizing The Installation**

```
   npm install
    npm run dev
    php artisan migrate
```